# Java use a method multiple times but with changed parameters

Tags: java, methods

I have a method reads coordinates from a file and uses them to render a GameObject at the specified coordinates writen on the file, this code looks like this:

```
public void ProcessText()
 {          
    String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";

    try
    {           
        ProcessCoords file = new ProcessCoords(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);                    

             if(aryLines[i].startsWith("makeGrass:")) {
                    String Arguments = aryLines[i].substring(aryLines[i].indexOf(":")+1, aryLines[i].length());
                    String[] ArgArray = Arguments.substring(1, Arguments.length() - 2).split(" ");

                    this.makeGrass(Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[0]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[1]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[2]));
            }
        }   
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

and my text file would only have one line:

```
makeGrass:(x y z)           // for example makeGrass:(1.22334 0.0 9.66678)
```

this all works fine now.. but there's no point in making this for only one single object. What I want to be able to do is have as many objects as I want from multiple coordinates, so my text file might look like this:

```
makeGrass:(0.0 1.0 5.0) 
makeGrass:(8.0 1.0 2.0) 
makeGrass:(4.0 1.0 7.0) 
makeGrass:(0.0 1.0 2.0) 
makeGrass:(2.0 1.0 7.0) 
makeGrass:(5.0 1.0 6.0)
```

at the moment I use the code this.makeGrass only once and like that my grass model is only placed at those coordinates of the first line (the other lines cause a graphical glitch where they are just being put ontop of each other)

My question here is how I have to write the code so it gives me this.makeGrass multiple times: I want to render the grass model at the respective makeGrass coordinates as many times as there are makeGrass coordinates provided in the text file, how can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

edit: I was asked for more information.. here it is:

```
public class Vegetation extends GameComponent
{
private Game game;

GameObject grassLeaf1 = new GameObject();
Mesh grassLeaf1mesh = new Mesh("grassLeaf1.obj");
Material grassLeaf1material = new Material
(new Texture("GrassUVTex.png"), 1, 8, new Texture("GrassUVTex_NRM.jpg"), new Texture("GrassUVTex_DISP.jpg"), 0.008f, -0.5f);
MeshRenderer grassLeaf1Renderer = new MeshRenderer(grassLeaf1mesh, grassLeaf1material);

public Vegetation(Game game)
{
    this.game = game;
}

public void makeGrass(double posX, double posY, double posZ)
 {       
    grassLeaf1.AddComponent(grassLeaf1Renderer);
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().GetPos().Set((float)posX, (float)posY, (float)posZ);
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().SetScale(new Vector3f (2, 2, 2));
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().SetRot(new Quaternion(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), (float) Math.toRadians(0)));     
    game.AddObject(grassLeaf1);
 }  

 public void ProcessText()
 {   
    grassLeaf1.AddComponent(new SaveGrass());
    grassLeaf1.AddComponent(new ObjectManipulator(4.0f)); 

    String file_name = "C:/Users/Server/Desktop/textText.txt";

    try
    {           
        ProcessCoords file = new ProcessCoords(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i]);                    

             if(aryLines[i].startsWith("makeGrass:")) {
                    String Arguments = aryLines[i].substring(aryLines[i].indexOf(":")+1, aryLines[i].length());
                    String[] ArgArray = Arguments.substring(1, Arguments.length() - 2).split(" ");

                    this.makeGrass(Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[0]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[1]), 
                                   Double.parseDouble(ArgArray[2]));
            }
        }   
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

The  Vegetation Class handles creating a grass model and reading the coordinates of it from a text file. This here is said text file:

```
makeGrass:(0.6 1.0 2.8)
makeGrass:(5.6 1.0 9.8)
makeGrass:(2.6 1.0 4.8)
makeGrass:(7.6 1.0 3.8)
makeGrass:(0.6 1.0 2.8)
makeGrass:(0.6 1.0 4.8)
makeGrass:(2.6 1.0 2.8)
makeGrass:(0.6 1.0 0.8)
```

Now this should enable me to render 8 grass models at different positions but when I hit run all I can see is this:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27752444/Untitled.png.html

the grass is also super shiny because all other grass models are being placed also at this location.. something went wrong..

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is from what you have shown. If the makeGrass function does what you intend it to, the above should work. Could you also show the makeGrass function and overall class definition?

Comment: If the makeGrass method works correctly and is static, then it should work for any specified parameters an infinite number of times. The makeGrass method could be modifying the object data that causes future calls to fail

Comment: Like Jonathan said, if the statement System.out.println(aryLines[i]); can print out all lines, then your file read function is correct. Maybe you should check you makeGrass function.

Comment: I've added some more information to my question maybe now the bug can be found.. oh I've already found it...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found the mistake my make grass function was messed up, it needs to be like this:

```
public void makeGrass(double posX, double posY, double posZ)
 {       
    GameObject grassLeaf1 = new GameObject();
    Mesh grassLeaf1mesh = new Mesh("grassLeaf1.obj");
    Material grassLeaf1material = new Material
    (new Texture("GrassUVTex.png"), 1, 8, new Texture("GrassUVTex_NRM.jpg"), new Texture("GrassUVTex_DISP.jpg"), 0.008f, -0.5f);
    MeshRenderer grassLeaf1Renderer = new MeshRenderer(grassLeaf1mesh, grassLeaf1material);
    grassLeaf1.AddComponent(grassLeaf1Renderer);
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().GetPos().Set((float)posX, (float)posY, (float)posZ);
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().SetScale(new Vector3f (2, 2, 2));
    grassLeaf1.GetTransform().SetRot(new Quaternion(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), (float) Math.toRadians(0)));     
    game.AddObject(grassLeaf1);
}
```

only strange that once I've added the code into the makeGrass method I lost my input methods.. strange but not that of a problem for now..

I'm getting almost exactly what I wanted now.. here's the final result and the basis of my world editor. Thank you all very much, you've really helped me!

Here's my ShowOff picture: http://www.pic-upload.de/view-27752521/ShowOff.png.html

I'm sure I'll be back for more soon enough but at the moment I know everything and can extend this world editor on my own, thanks a lot to all who have helped me so far, hopefully I can return the favour some time!